# How can I call the jQuery function: animate from outside the html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a website and recently i have picked up a few things about jQuery.

The problem is when i want to put my function out of my index file it does nothing.

This is in my index file:

```
<head>
<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(right())
</script></head>
```

and this is what my scripts.js contains:

```
function right() {
$("#right").animate({right: '0'}, 800);}
```

the #right is a div inside my index file.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Change the order of your script tags in most cases jQuery has to be loaded first, it wont solve your problem but it will help for future

Comment: In addition to what @code said, you will need to read up on how to call functions in JavaScript - i.e. no jQuery wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling it from a script tag inside the body rather than the head. Alternatively, if you want to do it from within the head, call it from within a block like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    right();
});
```

For JavaScript to execute, it either needs to be inside the body of the document, or it needs to be set to trigger on an event (in this case, the event is "when the document is ready").